# ABI-compatible Observer pattern for custom types (C++)

Tags: c++, serialization, dll, observer-pattern, abi

I embarked on the endeavor of implementing the observer pattern over ABI-compatible plug-ins (dynamic libraries) in C++. 
I can achieve the observer registration and notification calls over the dll boundary with COM-style pure virtual interfaces,
with both the observer and observable objects allocated and freed in their respective memory allocation space.

However, the goal of the project is to produce and consume custom data types (structs, classes) with the pull observer pattern.
It seems to me that ABI-compatibility restricts me to using POD types only. What would be a solution for custom data types?
I began looking at (de)serialization with boost perhaps, but I am not sure I am on the right track. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: De-/Serialization is probably a good idea. You could also have a look at google protobuf.

Comment: Indeed serialization looks like the way to go. Protobuf is great. You could implement something yourself using boost. See this talk for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbZdZKpUVeg

Comment: Protobuf is already in the project and was meant to be used for an RPC implementation of the same observer pattern over TCP. So it is definitely in my visor. Wanted to have a dynamic library plug-in framework too for higher performance local plug-ins. If I have to (de)serialize everything it might not be worth all the work, however.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do I distribute the protobuf library? The plug-ins that produce and consume the protocols defined by me have to: include either the .proto or the C++ class AND link to the protobuf lib. Since I am striving for ABI compatibility, the plug-in writer has to compile it him/herself. Is there a subset of protobuf source files I can provide (like boost BCP)?